# How to get card to resize when screen size is changed

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, position

I have a webpage with a navigation bar and a card with information on it. The navigation bar resizes with the screen but I'm struggling to get the card to do the same
[image: Gif]. I've tried changing the px to rem in the CSS but that doesn't seem to work. I've also tried making a wrapper that goes around the elements within the body of the HTML but that hasn't solved the problem either.

If anyone can help me with this I'd be really appreciative.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">[Ayanfe]:)</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./Pages/1/index.html" class="active">Next</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <main>

  <a href="#" class="card">
      <div class="inner">
        <time class="subtitle">Before I delve into my pitch, I think its important to acknowledge that present me is much different from younger me. Growing up, I was extroverted, trusting and extremely open to people. As life progressed the realities of the world became more apparent and the world that lived inside my head became a lot more attractive.<time>
            <br>
            <br>

        <time class="Key">Keyword: Escapism<time>


      </div>

 
  </a>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



body {
   background-color: black;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vh;
}

header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.875rem 6.25rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    z-index: 10000;
}

header .logo {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.563rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.313rem;

}

header ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

header ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

header ul li a {
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 0.375rem 0.938rem;
     color: #fff;
     border-radius: 1.25rem;

}

header ul li a:hover,
header ul li a.active {
    background: #fff;
    color: #2b1055;
}

main,
footer {
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card {
  height: 28.125rem;
  position: relative;
  left: 18.75rem;
  top: 12.5rem;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0.25rem solid;
  border-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  background: url(./Images/1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 105%;
  margin: auto;

}

@include media {
    height: 500px;

}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
  
  @include media {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }


.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;  
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #181818;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #a6f8d5;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
  
  @include media {
    font-size: 30px;
  }


.subtitle {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}


.content-wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 60rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to remove the `body {...}` option and then responsiveness will work for `<a class="card">`.  Plus I added some `@media(max-width: ... px)` settings.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
   background-color: black;
}

header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.875rem 6.25rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    z-index: 10000;
}

header .logo {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.563rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.313rem;

}

header ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

header ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

header ul li a {
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 0.375rem 0.938rem;
     color: #fff;
     border-radius: 1.25rem;

}

header ul li a:hover,
header ul li a.active {
    background: #fff;
    color: #2b1055;
}

main,
footer {
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card {
  height: 28.125rem;
  width: 70%;
  position: relative;
  left: 18.75rem;
  top: 12.5rem;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0.25rem solid;
  border-color: black;
  background: url(./Images/1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 105%;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

/*
@include media {
    height: 500px;

}*/

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
  
 /* @include media {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }*/


.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;  
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #181818;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #a6f8d5;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
  
  /*@include media {
    font-size: 30px;
  }*/


.subtitle {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Key{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.content-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

@media(max-width: 1000px) {
    .Key, .subtitle {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
}
@media(max-width: 750px) {
    .Key, .subtitle {
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    }

    .inner {
        height: 70%;
    }
}
@media(max-width: 720px) {
    .Key, .subtitle {
        font-size: 0.6rem;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <header>
            <a href="#" class="logo">[Ayanfe]:)</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./Pages/1/index.html" class="active">Next</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>

        <a href="#" class="card">
            <div class="inner">
                    <time class="subtitle">Before I delve into my pitch, I think its important to acknowledge that present me is much different from younger me. Growing up, I was extroverted, trusting and extremely open to people. As life progressed the realities of the world became more apparent and the world that lived inside my head became a lot more attractive.<time>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                <time class="Key">Keyword: Escapism<time>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You've solved the majority of my problem. I'm just having some issue with the inner box leaving the background when the screen is resized. Do you have any idea how to solve this? [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iqic0vRx_7Sk8dhlvgYYjbBmHuWIYEe9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi! I see the problem. I'm here to help! Could you send me code to add it via example jsfiddle link or txt file. Enough just about the modification as well, because as I can see in the background it changes the card size. The original version had a fixed size so it doesn't crawl out of the inner box for me. So at first glance I think of `.inner{height: 90%; position: absolute;}`.

Comment: Hi, here's a link [link]https://jsfiddle.net/98ssvm/5np2djL8/6/  . Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Hi! I have prepared a solution to your problem. Here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/5hvLcnx0/

Comment: Thank you so much. it works perfectly!!

Comment: You are very welcome! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You have the width of `.inner` set to `500px`.
That means it will always stay 500px, independent of screen size.

Try using a percentage instead - your header has `width: 100%`, that's why it changes width on resize.

If you need more flexibility than that, calc() allows you to calculate a value with different units, such as `width: calc(20% - 10px + 2rem)`

Comment: Hi, I already tried this by converting the px to rem but the problem still remained. I just changed the width to 60% but it's still not resizing. Do you have any more suggestions?